# How Can I Display the Category Description in a Theme with no Category.php or Archive.php?

Tags: categories, archives, description

I'm trying to display the category description on category pages below the title (category name). The challenge is that my theme is based on _s and doesn't have category.php or archive.php files because they're created dynamically. In my child theme, I've found the locations of the content, but inserting an echo of the category description doesn't work.

```
<h2 class="entry-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>">
         <?php the_title();?>
    </a>
</h2><!-- .entry-title -->
<div class="page-description"> 
    <?php echo category_description( 413 );?>
</div>
```

I tried making a function to call the description and inserting that instead, but no luck.

The only thing that has successfully called the description anywhere on my site is a shortcode, but I can't get that to work on a category archive page because I can't make it work in the backend.

```
add_shortcode('cat_desc', 'cat_desc_shortcode');
function cat_desc_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
        'slug' => null,
    ), $atts );

    if( $a['id'] ) {
        $cat = get_category( $a['id'] );
    } elseif( $a['slug'] ) {
        $cat = get_category_by_slug( $a['slug'] );
    } else {
        $cat = get_the_category()[0];
    }

    if( $cat == null ) return;

    $output = '<div class="page-description"> '.$cat->description.' </div> ';

    return $output;
}
```

I really only need to be able to show one specific description for one specific category page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason you can't create archive.php or category.php in your child theme. The parent theme doesn't need to have it for you to add it. Just copy index.php and rename it, then make any changes you need. You can use `the_archive_description()` to display the category description.

Comment: Also, you mention using _s and a child theme. You're not just creating a child theme of _s are you? That's not how _s is supposed to be used.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! I'll try making a category.php and see if it breaks the site. I'm using WP Portfolio, which is based on _s.

Comment: The structure of the site has a "sidebar.php" and a "content.php" file, but then all of the actual content is in included "extension" files. There's a loop_for_archive function that calls the category title and I was hoping I'd be able to stick the description below it, but what seems so simple is not.

Comment: Ok, so I tried making a category.php, also renaming it to archive.php. The site is such a hacked up thing with hooks pulling from all over the place (including some "do_actions" without any "add_actions"??) that I can't make it work. Then, I tried just directly pasting in my description text to see if that works and it does not. WTF? Is it possible that the theme is somehow dynamically blocking or deleting anything after the title in that div?

Comment: It's impossible to say without having access to the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jacob! I ended up just giving up and making a regular page for the one category that I wanted to show a description. It doesn't quite look like the other category pages, but it works and I can't spend more time on it.